# Linq Query Fails With Null Value

Tags: linq, datatables, predicate

I am using JQuery Datatables with my MVC 5 application. I am implementing sorting on one of my datatables within my MVC Controller, however, I am having some difficulties because it appears some of the columns which a user can choose to sort by, contains null values.

```
//Get column index to sort
var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);

if (sortColumnIndex == 0 || sortColumnIndex == 1)
{
    if(sortColumnIndex == 0)
    {
         Func<survey_status, string> orderingFunction = (c => c.doctor.Doctor_FName);
    }
    else if(sortColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        Func<survey_status, string> orderingFunction = (c => c.Facilitator.Doctor_FName);
    }
}
```

If the `sortColumnIndex` is 0, then there is never a problem because `c.doctor` is never Null. However, when the `sortColumnIndex` is 1, then sometimes `c.Facilitator` is Null, which makes the code fail.

Is there anything I can do check if c.Facilitator is Null, if so, return an empty string like "" or "No data".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(c => c.Facilitator == null ? "No Data" : c.Facilitator.Doctor_FName)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and speedy response.